# Best way to load a byte for write

Tags: performance, assembly, x86

To read and then write a byte from and to memory, you can choose between a few options, among them:

Load a 32-bit value, write out a byte:

```
mov eax, [rdi]
mov byte [rsi], al
```

Load a byte, write a byte:

```
mov al, byte [rdi]
mov byte [rsi], al
```

Load a byte, zero extended, write a byte:

```
movzx eax, byte [rdi]
mov byte [rsi], al
```

All the approaches are the same on the *write* side, but they use different ways of reading the value. Is there any reason to prefer one over the others, particularly performance-wise?

Comment: The second one, because that doesn't break alignment, doesn't break operand size and doesn't overread. Also it does what it says :) PS: the third one should be `movzx eax`

Comment: That's what I would think, but apparently that's the only form that takes 2 (fused) uops on Intel, all the others take 1. The third one doesn't break alignment or overread, right? What does "break operand size" mean? @Jester

Comment: Accessing a different sized part of the same register usually incurs some penalty (but haven't checked specifically).

Comment: IIRC that's only if some writes the smaller parts are involved. E.g., a write to `al` followed by a read from `ax` or `eax` or whatever needs to either reconstitute the `eax` register from parts (recent Intel IIRC), or the write itself may suffer a cost to merge (older Intel IIRC). Only _reading_ the smaller regs has always been OK, I think. @Jester

Comment: on latest x86 the last one is 1 uops as you noted yourself. (I wonder whether that would really make a difference in real life, unless we are talking some big data processing tuned for particular CPU target). I would use second way just because I'm used to it and reads better to me (as long as profiling wouldn't mark this as a problematic bottleneck).

Comment: @Ped7g - that right, this mostly tightly matter except in tight kernels with a lot of byte stores (which do exist). On the other hand, I disagree with your "for a particular CPU target" - _all_ recent Intel back to Ivy Bridge has this cost, so if you are in a data center say, it would be tuning for 99% of currently used CPU targets.

Comment: @SODIMM the question what intrigues me is "does it matter?" In such data centre, if you would use `movzx` properly, how many times that saved single uop would result in performance boost or saved energy? Would it be measurable? Let's say if you would compile only OS kernels (running apps not under your control): would it yield something? It's hard for me to believe it would be significant. If yes, then why do we use abominations like Java/... so much, those are not 1 uop more, but hundreds of them (easy to beat even by hand asm). Not even talking about this late javascript fashion...

Comment: what I mean by that ... IMO there are much better targets, what to change/redo to save much more, than reasoning about single additional uop in places where L1 cache miss is actually likely in like 1/3 of case by my guesstimate. If I would be writing hand asm, I wouldn't be bothered by this at all, design of algorithm and data and overall architecture would be better targets to spend time on. If I would be working on compiler, then ok, this may be worth few moments of reasoning, but we're probably running already off budget by this discussion here.

Comment: Well those are very philosophical questions, but I'm sure there is at least some scenario where it matters. The idea that you should focus on design/overall algorithm for hand-written asm is of course a false dichotomy: of course you should do as well as possible as you can there, but there is still room for tuning once those decisions are made. You could apply your argument repeatedly to basically conclude that writing only in the highest of high level languages makes sense :) @Ped7g